# dyld: dyld_sim not compatible mach-o

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, ios11, xcode9

I installed Xcode 9 and trying to run my app on ios simulator 11.0. As soon as it launches the app its crashing giving this error. What does this error mean? If my app is not compatible with ios11.0, how can I check for the compatibily?

**EDIT** - Uploaded my valid Architectures

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you please show complete error?

Comment: This is the only line I could see in the debug console - dyld: dyld_sim not compatible mach-o

crashes with SIGABRT

Comment: Did you figure out what is going on? I have the same issue. I think it is because a library doesn't support 64bit. I am still looking at it, not sure how to fix it

Comment: Yeah.. Even I think so, I am trying to update libraries.. Hopefully could run it once I upload the library..

Answer (score 53):

You need to make these changes in `build setting`  ... it works for me [image]

Comment: @birdcage in your code you set the Alfa value that will be return 0 ,,, change it to 1.  -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46441078/uiimage-view-is-not-showing-in-ios-11-how-to-solve/46541633#46541633

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem and found out that the architectures and valid architectures settings for my targets (and pods) were set wrong. iOS 11 doesn't support 32bit applications anymore, so I guess that took part in my problem..,

I've deleted my architectures + valid architectures settings (made it default) and now it compiles and runs fine in both simulator and iOS 11 device. hope it helps u as well ;).

Comment: Can you please let me know what architectures it has been set currently now?

Comment: arm64 armv7 armv7s. but you just need to press delete on that field - that will unset your setting and will use the default one.

Comment: Deleting the valid architecture is not working for me