# UIImage view is not showing in iOS 11.....How to solve?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, ios11

I have an existing project in iOS, it was working fine with till `iOS 10`,
After updating `X-Code 9` , and run the project `iOS 10` it is fine but in `iOS 11` the `UIImageview` is not showing ..

I have already tried so many ways like clean derived data, reset clean build with quit x-code and restart system, remove and add image(png file),  but noting happen.

Even i have added the background colour but the colour is also not showing in the device and simulator but it is in the storyboard .

one more thing ,,, the background image on `UIButton` is showing but on the image it is not displaying.

Is any one find solution ?

Comment: can you show your code or some screenshots ?

Comment: make a demo project with imageview and provide same image and pls let me know what you are getting.

Comment: it is working fine with new project. I already tried. and one more thing with another old project images are working fine and I have cross check with that both code and properties are same.

Comment: @NiravKotecha this is not with a single image ,, in hole project around 130 viewcontroller's and same code is working file with iOS 10 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly `Debug` through `View hierarchy` and Check Image `Alpha Value`. Remove This line of code from your project if not necessary -

`[super setAlpha:0];`