# iOS: Twitter-OAuth library architecture problems

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter, twitter-oauth

I have an old `objective-c` application that can't run in `iOS 11.0` devices. To solve this issue I have changed the architecture (from the `build settings`) to the `standard architecture` (the same as the answer of this SO [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46323700/dyld-dyld-sim-not-compatible-mach-o)) and the `Build Archive Architecture Only` is having `YES` for the `Debug` and `NO` for the others. The [Twitter-OAuth](https://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone) library is included in this project. The build always fails because of those errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_OARequestParameter", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SA_OAuthTwitterEngine.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_OAMutableURLRequest", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SA_OAuthTwitterEngine.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_OADataFetcher", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SA_OAuthTwitterEngine.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_OAToken", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SA_OAuthTwitterEngine.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_OAConsumer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SA_OAuthTwitterEngine.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The version of this library is old (its architecture is not supporting 64 bit). When I replace it with the new version I got a lot of errors between them the errors on the top. I tried to keep the old version, I replaced the `libOAuth.a` with the new one and all the files mentioned in the errors with the new ones. But I'm still getting the same problem. I know that the best solution is to use the new `Twitter SDK` (via `Fabric`) but I wonder if I can keep this library and solve those architecture problems.

Can anyone guide me please?

Comment: iOS11 will not accept 32 Bit apps, libraries included.  You'll either have to use a new library, or upgrade the old one to 64bit yourself.  TBH, I'd bite the bullet and move to a newer SDK.

Comment: @GeorgeBrown the new version of the Twitter-OAuth is made for the 64 Bit. But I don't know why I'm still getting architecture problems with it. If I use a new SDK, I must recode a whole part of the application

Comment: @Lig Looking at libOAuth at https://github.com/x42/liboauth it also hasn't been updated in years.  All of your errors above are objects in that library (OARequestParameter, OAMutableRequest etc).  I'm not that great with c, but the library is probably still using 32 bit types.

Comment: @GeorgeBrown thank you but the `libOAuth.a` is inside the Twitter-OAuth https://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone/tree/master/Twitter%2BOAuth/Libraries%20%26%20Headers. This new version supports the 64 Bit because when I run `lipo -info  libOAuth.a` I get the 32 BIt and the 64 Bit architecture.