# Error showing : dyld_sim is not compatible with the loaded process

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a source code of an app that is live in iPhone (for OS iOS 7 and before) and it is not supported in iOS 8.0 and later. When I tried to compile the code it is executing all the files fine, but it is throwing an architecture mismatch error.

In console:

> dyld: dyld_sim is not compatible with the loaded process, likely due
>   to architecture mismatch

I tried adding valid architectures (armv7 armv7s arm64) in Build settings for both iPhone and Xcode iOS simulators. Still doesn't fix the issue...

Please help me...

I am using Xcode 9.2.

[Valid Architectures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57lft.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dyld: dyld\_sim not compatible mach-o](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46323700/dyld-dyld-sim-not-compatible-mach-o)

Comment: @Berendschot  Thanks for the comment. Sorry, my mistake. it worked for me but, nowhere it is mentioned that I had to add valid architectures to both project and target Build Settings. That took me a while to figure it. Anyway, I finally made it compile and run.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Follow the steps below. Hope it will work.....

1. Change Deployment target to recent one like **>= 9.0**
2. Select **Standard architectures** for **Architectures** from Build Settings> Architectures

[image]

[image]

Comment: This solution worked with **Xcode 10.1** when trying to use with downloaded Apple sample code AVSimpleEditoriOS. Thanks.