# LibGDX simulating iOS with RoboVM crashes with architecture mismatch error

Tags: ios, libgdx, robovm

When I attempt to run my LibGDX project via the RoboVM iPhone simulator it crashes immediately on launch and gives the following error:

`dyld: dyld_sim is not compatible with the loaded process, likely due to architecture mismatch`

I'm really unsure as to what this means. Any help is appreciated, please let me know if I need to provide more information.

EDIT:

In the file named "build.gradle" there is an option `archs = "thumbv7:arm64"` and I'm wondering whether I need to change this, as I'm assuming `archs` refers to architectures.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48662735/error-showing-dyld-sim-is-not-compatible-with-the-loaded-process/51740671

Comment: @Aryan I'm not using XCode to run the project so I can't do what that answer says to do, which requires changing the build settings within XCode. My project is being run from Eclipse with RoboVM, but utilises the XCode simulator.

Answer (score 1):

- How are you launching your the RoboVM build?
  I do it by running the following command line from my project root folder:
  ./gradlew ios:launchiPhoneSimulator
- I think before you launch on your simulator you need a provisioning profile installed on your computer.

if you have that, 
My  working Gradle contains:

```
robovm {
    iosSignIdentity = "mysigning identity"
    iosProvisioningProfile = "my provisioning profile"
    iosSkipSigning = false
    archs = "thumbv7:arm64"
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Eclipse.

You have to choose 64 bits instead of 32 bits in the Run Configuration settings.